# Error with Vuetify 2.0 plugin in nuxt project: [vite-node] [ERR_LOAD_URL] vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass

Tags: sass, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, vite

I’m a absolute beginner developer who’s trying to install Vuetify 2.0 into a Vue Nuxt.js 3 project.

I tried following the steps below but I keep on getting this error:

**[vite-node] [ERR_LOAD_URL] vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass at vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass (imported from virtual:nuxt:./.nuxt/css.mjs)
**

and in the VS code project terminal I get this: **Failed to resolve import "vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass" from "virtual:nuxt:/Users/myName/projectName/projectFolder/.nuxt/css.mjs". Does the file exist?
**

I would be forever grateful for any advice or reference to what might be the issue.

(Side note: I wanted to use vuetify 2.0 because some features in vuetify3 are not stable yet like the v-data-table.)

What I did:

1. yarn add vuetify@2.0 sass
2. Create a plugins folder and create new vuetify.js file inside.
3. Wrote this inside plugins/vuetify.js:

```
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
export default defineNuxtPlugin(nuxtApp => {
    const vuetify = createVuetify({
        components,
        directives,
})
nuxtApp.vueApp.use(vuetify)
})
```

4. Wrote this inside nuxt.config.ts file:

```
import { defineNuxtConfig } from 'nuxt'

export default defineNuxtConfig({

 //some non-vuetify related configurations…

    css: ['vuetify/lib/styles/main.sass'],
    build: {
        transpile: ['vuetify'],
   },
vite: {
    define: {
        'process.env.DEBUG': false,
    },
  },
})
```